# DataFrame.where, error using array as condition

Tags: python, pandas

Why doesn't `DataFrame.where` allow for the same flexibility as most other DataFrame slices, where an array of shape (X,) can be use to slice the rows. Instead it needs to be explicitly reshaped to (X, N), N being the number of columns, otherwise there's a `ValueError`. Is there something I'm missing, or some argument that allows for the normal (X,) array to be used as the condition. It seems like it *should* work from the description:

> cond : boolean Series/DataFrame, array-like, or callable

---

#### Illustration

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = [list('aaaabbbb'), [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]]
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 2), index=idx, columns=['col1'])

m = df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated()
#array([False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True])

# `loc` is smart enough to deal with this array.
df.loc[m]

# This fails:
df.where(m)
#ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self
```

---

I don't quite see what the `axis` argument does. It doesn't seem to broadcast the array as I'd expect, which works properly for other functions.

```
# .add works as expected
df.add(m, axis=0)

df.where(m, axis=0)
#ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self
```

---

What's perhaps the most puzzling is how the alignment seems to be different from what you'd normally expect. I can create a Series

```
s = pd.Series(m, index=idx)
#a  1    False
#   2     True
#   3     True
#   4     True
#b  1    False
#   2     True
#   3     True
#   4     True
#dtype: bool
```

With most `pandas` operations, it requires alignment on both the Row and Column Index. The following makes sense to me; the Column Index doesn't overlap so I get an error. If I tell it to align on the index, it will broadcast the addition properly:

```
df.add(s)
#ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names

df.add(s, axis=0)
#         col1      col2
#a 1  0.496714 -0.138264
#  2  1.647689  2.523030
#  3  0.765847  0.765863
#  4  2.579213  1.767435
#b 1 -0.469474  0.542560
#  2  0.536582  0.534270
#  3  1.241962 -0.913280
#  4 -0.724918  0.437712
```

On the other hand, `where` seems to be fine, regardless of specifying the axis.

```
df.where(s) # or df.where(s, axis=1) or df.where(s, axis=0)
#         col1      col2
#a 1       NaN       NaN
#  2  0.647689  1.523030
#  3 -0.234153 -0.234137
#  4  1.579213  0.767435
#b 1       NaN       NaN
#  2 -0.463418 -0.465730
#  3  0.241962 -1.913280
#  4 -1.724918 -0.562288
```

Comment: Weird indeed. `df.where(pd.Series(m,index=idx))` clearly works, and `pd.Series(m,index=idx).shape` is the same as `m`

Comment: @MarkWang yes, My guess is that's the safest way to do this. Even though the shape is the same, somehow it's aligning on the index. But surprisingly it knows to only match on the row Index and doesn't check the column index. This seems entirely opposite from how most other things in pandas align.

Comment: Given how column assignment works e.g. `df['col'] = pd.series` and `df['col']=np.array`, I would expect `df.where` to work in the same fasion, i.e, when row index is available, align the index, when it's np.array, align the numeric position, while being able to broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

Both `df.where(...)` and `df.mask(...)` are functions to **update**
the "self" DataFrame or at least to decide where to take values from.

So no *boolean indexing* takes place here (as in *df.loc*).

*Pandas* checks **each element** of *condition* (the first argument) and
the result decides whether to take the value from respective
**element** of *other* or from *self*.

So, just as the error message says, its shape must be just the same as *self*
or at least it must be broadcastable to the shape of *self*.

In boolean indexing (e.g. *df.loc[m]*), the principle is different:
*m* is a *bool* **vector**, with each element serving as a criterion
for respective **whole row** (whether to include it in the result).

Note also that *np.vstack(m)* actually "regenerates" the *bool* array,
used in boolean indexing and since *df* has a single column,
it pertains to just this column.

If *df* contained e.g. **two** columns, an attempt to execute
`df.where(np.vstack(m))` would result in **just the same** error message,
this time because *np.vstack(m)* has **one** column.

Comment: Yes, your point about this working only because I have one column is good. However, I'm still a bit dissatisfied (not with your answer, but instead with `where`). `where` takes an `axis` argument, so I feel like I *should* be able to pass it an array that is the same shape as the Index and the broadcasting should work. `df.add(m.astype(int), axis=0)` will work fine (with multiple columns), but somehow `df.where(m, axis=0)` doesn't. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how `where` uses the `axis` argument.